# generate html with translation

Tags: pyramid, chameleon

For a generic form checker I want to generate html `<input>` fields plus internationalized error messages (and default values, ...) while using templates to define which fields are in the form.

**Template example:**

```
...
<form>
  ${structure: make_field('email')}
</form>
```

**Rendered template:**

```
...
<form>
  <input type="text" name="email" ... /><span>error message</span>
</form>
```

**Problem:**

The error message for each field is specified using gettext like `_('error123')`. Because the html string is constructed by code I have to `translate()` the error message myself. Therefore I have to hand in a localizer to the form checker code which I want to avoid.

Is it possible to move the rendering completely to the template engine. Maybe with macros generated in code?!

Comment: You'll need to provide information here about how `make_field` is implemented; does it use a form framework?